# Deserialize only give me 0 as value

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

my problem is simple, when I deserialise this file all values are set to 0.
Some code will be more explicit.

Main class :

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        Elements file = null;
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            load_map("clxml.xml");
        }

        public void load_map(string path)
        {
            // deserialize xmlfile_config_map
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Elements));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            try
            {
                file = (Elements)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            }catch(Exception e){

            }
            MessageBox.Show((file.listObjet[1].id).ToString());
            MessageBox.Show((file.listObjet[2].pos_x).ToString());
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

class that I fill:

```
//[Serializable]
public class Element
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("pos_x")]
    public int pos_x { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("pos_y")]
    public int pos_y { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("rot")]
    public int rot { get; set; }
}

//[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("droot")]
public class Elements
{
    [XmlElement("Element")]
    public List<Element> listObjet { get; set; }
```

and the xml file :

```
 <Element id="4" pos_x="85" pos_y="43" rot="34"/>
```

which is line like this, but I don't think the problem comes from here.

Comment: We really need to see some sample of the XML, from the root element down...

Comment: xml was lost in edits ;)

Comment: @MauriceStam [Serializable] is not relevant for the scenario, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: [Serializable] commented cause can't find the assembly needed in a windows phone project.

Comment: I'm not familiarised with the System.Xml.Serialization but are you mixing elements and attributes?

Comment: i kept the [XmlElement] but i have changed the xml file : ' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <droot> <Element> 
<id>4</id> 
<pos_x>54</pos_x> <pos_y>5</pos_y> 
enter code here<rot>25</rot> 
</Element> <id>7</id><pos_x>52</pos_x> <pos_y>42</pos_y> <rot>14</rot> <Element> <id>3</id> <pos_x>37</pos_x> <pos_y>752</pos_y> <rot>52</rot> </Element>``</droot>'

Comment: @Gabson If that is your workaround (and final solution) please post it as an answer and accept it. However, you might want to consider my solution that answers your question.

Comment: @MauriceStam I ll finish this today and then post the answer, already thanks to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The serializer is expecting elements in the XML. Try change `[XmlElement]` to `[XmlAttribute]`.

The quickest way to find out deserialize issues is by *reverting the process*. Try serializing a dummy object and verify whether the output is correct.

```
        Elements elements = new Elements
        {
            listObjet = new List<Element>
            {
                new Element
                {
                    id = 1,
                    pos_x = 10,
                    pos_y = 20,
                    rot = 8
                }
            }
        };

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Elements));
        string output;
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, elements);
            output = writer.ToString();
        }

        // Todo: check output format
```

I have changed `[XmlElement]` to `[XmlAttribute]` for the `id` and `pos_x` properties. This was the output:

```
<Element id="1" pos_x="10">
  <pos_y>20</pos_y>
  <rot>8</rot>
</Element>
```